# Where can I find some open data about public transport flow?

Tags: public-transport

I am just finding some data about public transport flow which may meet these requirements as follows:

- It contains the flow per hour at a place in one city such as the number of passengers at the bus stop in London at 11 am.
- the flow change over time and different areas in **a** city.

Comment: Not a complete answer but you can start digging here: https://www.europeandataportal.eu

Answer (score 2):

[NYC Turnstile data](http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html) measures the cumulative number of entries and exits recorded every 4 hours for each of MTA's subway turnstiles between May 2010 and the present.  The data format for files older than 2014-10-18 can be viewed [here](http://web.mta.info/developers/resources/nyct/turnstile/ts_Field_Description_pre-10-18-2014.txt).  The current data format can be viewed [here](http://web.mta.info/developers/resources/nyct/turnstile/ts_Field_Description.txt).  There are numerous examples in which this data has been analyzed:

- [Human movement visualization (1)](https://chriswhong.com/open-data/visualizing-the-mtas-turnstile-data/) by Chris Whong
- [Human movement visualization (2)](https://digg.com/2018/manhattan-population-day-visualized) by Justin Fung
- [Data scraper and parser](https://piratefsh.github.io/projects/2015/10/03/mta-subway-turnstile-data.html) by Sher Minn Chong
- [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/new-york-state/nys-turnstile-usage-data)
- [Analysis of stations with high foot traffic](https://rjh336.github.io/projects/MTA-Turnstiles/) by Robert Hill